# The best way to enlarge images Android

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, image-enlarge

Suppose, we've got a display sized 100x100, an image 100x50, and I want to enlarge that image so that it has the same height as the screen does. So the image will be 200x100. After that I want to make the animation of image movement to the left and to the right. I've found 2 ways of the realization of my task:

1. To create a new image using `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`. But the
   image created this way will occupy twice more RAM.
2. To use `matrix.setScale()` in every `onDraw()`. But this works very
   slow. Is there any other better solution?

Comment: `So the image will be 200x100` - NO. It will be 100*100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method is slow because you calculate your "matrix" on every frame! Since your matrix is always the same thing and it does not change, you can pre-calculate your matrix and save it as a "field" in you class, then just use this function to draw it on screen:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, Paint paint)
```

It should be fast enough. The other option is to use:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)
```

Again, try to pre-calculate stuff as much as possible. In this case, pre-calc src and dst rectangles.